# Owin security handlers - Claims not generated on some requests

Tags: c#, owin, claims-based-identity

I am using Owin security handlers for validating the Azure AD JWT, as shown in the below sample:

https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WebAPI-OpenIDConnect-DotNet

In my WebApi, I have created a method with the [Authorize] attribute to validate the token. This method invokes the Owin security handlers to verify that the token is valid and the claims are generated for the request.

```
[System.Web.Mvc.Authorize]
    private static bool IsTokenValid()
    {
        LoggingUtilities.Logger.TraceInformation("Validating JWT.");
        return ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims != null;
    }
```

This works fine in most of the cases, but for some requests even though the token exists in the request, the claims are not fully generated.

Here is when all the claims are generated:
[image: Claims Generated]

When the claims are NOT generated correctly:
[image: Claims Not Generated]

Both the times, the request has the valid JWT token.

Any help in troubleshooting the issue would be highly appreciated!

**`Update:`**
I have realized that those specific requests are not authenticated (looks like a bug in the Owin Katana handlers) by the security handler even though the request the valid token.

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Tenant = validTenant,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidAudience = validAudience,
                }
            });
```

Wondering if there is a way to force authenticate the user for the above Owin security handler setup when the request is not authenticated.